# Go & Socket.io HTTP + WSS on one port with CORS?

Tags: go, websocket, socket.io, cors

Brand new to Go.. Still obviously learning the syntax and the basics.. But I do have a specific goal in mind..

I'm trying to just get a simple server up on :8080 that can respond to both HTTP and socket.io (via `/socket.io/` url), specificaly with CORS.

My code:

```
package main

import (
     "log"         
     "net/http"
     "github.com/rs/cors"
     "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"
 )

 func SayHelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     w.Write([]byte("Hello, World!"))
 }

 func main() {

   c := cors.New(cors.Options{
         AllowedOrigins: []string{"*"},
         AllowCredentials: true,
   })

   server, err := socketio.NewServer(nil)
     if err != nil {
         log.Fatal(err)
     }


   server.On("connection", func(so socketio.Socket) {
      log.Println("on connection")
      so.Join("chat")
      so.On("chat message", func(msg string) {
          log.Println("emit:", so.Emit("chat message", msg))
          so.BroadcastTo("chat", "chat message", msg)
      })
      so.On("disconnection", func() {
          log.Println("on disconnect")
      })
   })

   server.On("error", func(so socketio.Socket, err error) {
      log.Println("error:", err)
   })    


   http.Handle("/socket.io/", c.Handler(server))
   http.HandleFunc("/", SayHelloWorld)
   log.Println("Serving at localhost:8080...")
   log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

On the client side I'm still seeing:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=xNWd9aZvwDnZOrXkOBaC' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
>
> (index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1420662449235-3932&sid=xNWd9aZvwDnZOrXkOBaC. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

***EDIT #1:***

So I've been banging my head away trying to understand why I can't connect.. Came across an even more confusing piece of the puzzle?

https://gist.github.com/acoyfellow/167b055da85248c94fc4

The above gist is the code of my golang server + the browser code used to connect.. This code will send 30 HTTP GET requests **per second** to the backend, without connecting, upgrading, or giving any errors (client or server side).. it essentially DDOS's my own backend?

Someone, please someone tell me I'm doing something stupid.. This is quite the pickle :P

***EDIT #2:***

I can stop the "DDOS" by simply adjusting the trailing `/` on the URL of the socket.io endpoint in Go.. So: `mux.Handle("/socket.io", server)` to `mux.Handle("/socket.io/", server)` will now produce error messages and connection attempts with error responses of:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=0TzmTM_QtF1TaS4exiwF' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400 socket.io-1.2.1.js:2
>
> GET https://api.domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1420743204485-62&sid=0TzmTM_QtF1TaS4exiwF 400 (Bad Request)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So I gave up using googoolee's Socket.io implementation and went with gorilla's.

I checked out their examples: https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat

Checked out their docs: http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/websocket
-- Under Origin Considerations I found:

> An application can allow connections from any origin by specifying a function that always returns true:
>
> var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
> CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool { return true },
> }

I added this `CheckOrigin` function to the `conn.go` file in their example, and was able to get a CORS socket server talking to a browser.

As a first adventure into Golang, this was frustrating and fun.. +1 to anyone else learning

Answer (score 3):

Don't you mean http + ws or https + wss. If you remove a s from wss, you should be able to connect.

If you want tls for web socket (wss), then you need to http.ListenAndServeTLS.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Upvoted so you can have commenting privileges now.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that CORS does not apply to WebSockets. Per this related question "With WebSocket, there is an "origin" header, which browser MUST fill with the origin of the HTML containing the JS that opens the WS connection."

As stated here: 
[Cross origin websockets with Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076658/cross-origin-websockets-with-golang)

Comment: Hmm.. I'm having trouble interpreting your answer (and the linked one). I already have a Node.js/Socket.io cluster that uses websockets over CORS no problem, so now I'm just confused even more. It sounds like your saying I need to send my origin from the client to the socket.io server, but I don't understand. Doesn't it automatically fill? I can't see anything in the Socket.io client API about setting a origin explicitly

Answer (score 0):

How about in your `SayHelloWorld` func, adding something like:

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

Or, possibly better:

```
if origin := r.Header.Get("Origin"); origin != "" {
  w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I tried that with no luck.. Same error responses in the client.. Connects, then disconnects stating:
`closed before the connection is established.
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.domain.com/socket.io/?...  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 0):

I get the similar problerm with normal ajax call. It require more work in both front-end and backend. I belive most popular front-end libs liek JQuery or AngularJS handle these very well.
I see you're using the https://github.com/rs/cors package but you don't include the usage of that package, here is the implement with only Go std package:

```
type CrossOriginServer struct {}

func (s *CrossOriginServer) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // you may need to add some more headers here
    allowHeaders := "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization"
    if origin := req.Header.Get("Origin"); validOrigin(origin) {
        rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
        rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, PATCH, GET, DELETE")
        rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", allowHeaders)
    }
    if req.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        return
    }

    // if you want, you can use gorilla/mux or any routing package here
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/socket.io/", c.Handler(server))
    mux.HandleFunc("/", SayHelloWorld)

    mux.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
}

func validOrigin(origin string) bool {
    allowOrigin := []string{
        "http://localhost:8081",
        "http://example.com"
    }

    for _, v := range allowOrigin {
        if origin == v {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

func main() {
    // do you stuff
    // ...
    // ...

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", &CrossOriginServer{})
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am trying our your solution now. As a side note, I'm confused as to why you mention I'm not using the cors package..
`c := cors.New(cors.Options{...})` is the first block of code under `main()` -- am I using this incorrectly?

Comment: I've tried out your solution here with no luck.. (https://gist.github.com/acoyfellow/72cfc18acb2f0eee0b96) but I'm still either: A) repeating my same mistake or B) doing something else wrong.